# cant read avro format issue in pyspark

Tags: avro

I tried to use the command line **df = spark.read.format("avro").load(path)**  and got an error saying "Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Apache Avro Data Source Guide".

I tried to resolve this couldn't find any solutions even after installing the packages and all, anybody please help me with this. thank you

Any other best way or suggestions on how to read avro files from s3 are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your spark submission like this:

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.5
```

or you manually put the package org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.5 in all jar folders of the spark installation (by all I mean driver and workers)

located under `$SPARK_HOME/jars/`

Comment: I get  Receiver class org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method  when using virtual env